# How to convert for loop to apply in r

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

I have the following loop. I am trying to convert it into using the `apply` function instead of a loop, but I don't know how to rewrite the code.

```
for (i in 1:dim(Y)[2]) {
     K = K_origin
     print(i)

     e = lmmlite::eigen_rotation(K, t(Y)[i,], use_cpp = T)
     VC = lmmlite::fitLMM(
       e$Kva,
       e$y,
       e$X,
       reml = T,
       use_cpp = T,
       tol = 1e-6,
       check_boundary = T
     )

     write.table(
       VC$sigmasq_g,
       "Vg_temp.txt",
       row.names = F,
       col.names = F,
       append = T,
       quote = F,
       sep = "\n"
     )
     write.table(
       VC$sigmasq_e,
       "Ve_temp.txt",
       row.names = F,
       col.names = F,
       append = T,
       quote = F,
       sep = "\n"
     )
}
```

I want results like these

```
Vg                  Ve
1.15521325512487    0.755118863386436
0.579039221720728   1.21733212837417
0.372439354137817   0.296327744338075
0.0668396114713355  0.300417453013007
0.00771158861391208 0.100176380868691
0.210174870097273   0.141907482831872
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

R's `apply` functions has to be formulated as 1) something to iterate over, and 2) a function to apply to each element in (1).

*But!* Whether you will gain anything from converting your particular loop into an apply, is doubtful. If your loop is slow, I am guessing it is due to the operations performed, not that "R is slow on loops". If you only have 6 rows in `Y`, you will gain nothing from re-formulating the loop into an apply!

For your loop, each `i` is independent (as opposed to looping over `i`, when a result depends on the calculation on `i-1`). So that makes it very easy to re-formulate. Generally,

```
for (i in some_sequence) {
  do something with i
}
```

can be reformulated to

```
my_do_something <- function(i) {
  do something
}

for (i in some_sequence) {
  my_do_something(i)
}
```

which can be again be directly reformulated to

```
sapply(some_sequence, my_do_something)
```

In your case, this would be

```
my_rotate <- function(i) {
  e = lmmlite::eigen_rotation(K, t(Y)[i,], use_cpp = T)
  VC = lmmlite::fitLMM( ... )
  write.table(...)
  write.table(...)
  NULL
}

sapply(seq_len(dim(Y)[2]), my_rotate)
```

Notice how I added an `NULL` at the bottom of the function? That would be because `apply` will gather the returned values from the iterated function; `write.table` returns the written data invisible. Try the function without the last `NULL` and see what `apply` returns.

*But wait, there's more!*

Since you are iterating over particular rows (and asking about `apply` in particular), let's just drop the `i` stuff and feed the function the row:

```
my_rotate_row <- function(x) {
  # you might or might not need to either use x as is, transpose it as t(x) or double transpose it, t(t(x)), to get the correct orientation. 
  # x is most likely an atomic vector, whereas `eigen_rotation` might be requiring either a row-vector or a column vector.

  e = lmmlite::eigen_rotation(K, x, use_cpp = T)
  VC = lmmlite::fitLMM( ... )
  # lets collect data directly into a data.frame or matrix, instead of using files:
  c(VC$sigmasq_g, VC$sigmasq_e)
}
```

Now you can use `apply`:

```
apply(Y, 2, my_rotate_row)
```